# Why does writing a <script> tag trigger jQuery.ajaxTransport() in 2.X?

Tags: jquery, ajax

It appears that recent builds of jQuery attempt to make their own AJAX request for the script source when appending a  tag to the document, e.g.:

```
 var script = $('<script/>', { id: 're_c', type: 'text/javascript', src: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js' });
 $('head').append(script);
```

this fails due to SOP:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js?legacy. Origin https://ark.dev.hypem.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery.js:7774
send jquery.js:7774
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7230
jQuery.extend._evalUrl jquery.js:5810
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery.js:5605
jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery.js:5387
(anonymous function)
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
InjectedScript.evaluate
Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

Looks like domManip fires jQuery._evalUrl( node.src ).

Meanwhile, $.getScript() works correctly.

Why was this behavior changed? Why not just write the literal script tag into the document and let the browser load the external resource as normal? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's designed to? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/ It's mentioned in the API documentation.

Comment: The code you provided worked fine for me using `jQuery 2.1`. Tested on `IE 11`, `Firefox 26` and `Chrome 32`. Which version of `jQuery` did you use and which browsers you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers do not accept it alltogether. Try this one:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js';
$("head").append( script );
```

It actually works but we cannot see it on some browsers due to jquery design. On [Jquery API Documentation, additional notes](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it says

> By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML
>   string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute
>   code.

So it actually performs the script and the result is cross domain issue.